# Why does $(1 + x)(1 + x^2)(1 + x^4)(1+x^8) \cdots = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, binary, infinite-product

Is there an *intuitive* explanation as to why $$(1 + x)(1 + x^2)(1 + x^4)(1+x^8) \cdots = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$$ for $
|{x}| < 1?$

Of course, we can show that each side of the equation is equal to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ fairly easily (RHS is the basic geometric series with common ratio of $x$ and LHS multiplied by $(1-x)$ will collapse the product to $1$)

^ This proof is perfect for a quick grasp on the equality, although it still remains unclear as to why an infinite product with factors of the form $1+x^{(2^n)}$ should expand into a simple G.S.

I would love to see a more direct proof that would at least make it more obvious as to why we can equate the product into the sum or vice-versa.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the constant term on LHS? What is the coefficient of $x$? Of $x^{2}$? ...

Comment: Would you consider “Using the binary representation of $n$, each $x^n$ on the RHS is the unique product of factors $x, x^2, x^4, x^8, \ldots$” an intuitive explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us rewrite the LHS as $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+x^{2^{n-1}})$. Let $P(k)=\prod_{n=1}^{k}(1+x^{2^{n-1}})$.
$$P(1)=x+1$$
$$P(2)=(1+x)(1+x^2)=x^2(x+1)+(x+1)=x^3+x^2+x+1$$
$$P(3)=(x^3+x^2+x+1)(1+x^4)=x^4(x^3+x^2+x+1)+(x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^7+x^6+\cdots+x+1$$
By observation, we notice that
$$P(a)=\sum_{n=0}^{2^a-1}x^n.$$
We shall prove this fact by induction.

$$P(1)=x+1$$
Note that
$$P(a)=(1+x^{2^{a-1}})P(a-1)=x^{2^{a-1}}P(a-1)+P(a-1). $$
Assume that
$$P(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{2^t-1}x^n.$$
Then
$$P(t+1)=x^{2^t}P(t)+P(t)=x^{2^t}\sum_{n=0}^{2^t-1}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{2^t-1}x^n=x^{2^t}(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2^t-1})+(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2^t-1})=(x^{2^t}+x^{2^t+1}+x^{2^t+2}+\cdots+x^{2^{t+1}-1})+(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2^t-1})=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2^{t+1}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{2^{t+1}-1}x^n. $$

Thus, by induction, we can conclude that $P(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{2^t-1}x^n.$ holds for all integers $t\ge1$.

As $t$ approaches infinity, we obtain that
$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdots=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots. $$

Comment: @jimjim Why this answer should receive downvotes (and why the threat)?

Comment: Can anyone tell me about the quality of my answer? I do not understand the downvote given.

Comment: This does not appear to as "intuitive" an explanation as the earlier answer, as requested in the question. But that is all I can say against it. It is a more formal argument supporting the reasoning in the other answer. I certainly would not downvote this and I don't see why it should be deleted.

Comment: @ICV , not a threat. The question was asking for intuitive explanation. The answer as correct as it is , did not seem intuitive, I saw it was already downvoted. Poster being new , made me think that h might get hammered by downvoted. Guess no need to remove it after all , just have bed memories of correct answers being downvoted as it did not make some people happy.

Comment: @JonathanZ , it was meant to be a helpful comment, I have seen low lives downvote a correct answer just because it did not satisfy some criteria of the question, when I saw the answer it was already downvoted for no reason at all.

Comment: @jimjim - Oh, it sounds like you were looking out for a new contributor - that's a very considerate thing to do. I don't think that came across in the comment you wrote, though. Maybe something like "FYI you might get down votes as this answer, though valid, probably doesn't count as 'intuitive'."?

Comment: @jimjim - Yeah, I can see that I totally misread it. I've deleted my above comments. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @jimjim for trying to help. I personally feel this is quite an intuitive answer as we make observations from defining an obvious function and go ahead to prove them by induction in a straightforward manner.

Comment: +1 for this answer. I've been observing some very toxic and entitled behavior lately on this forum, and it seems that you have fallen victim to that. Don't get discouraged though, it's only virtual points that literally nobody but the downvoters care about. Your answer should be the most upvoted.

Answer (score 8):

Any of the powers on the RHS can be written in the form $x^b$ where $b$ is a non-negative integer. Specifically, consider $b$ in binary. There is exactly one way to make a power of $x$ with degree $b$: for each digit in $b$ which is a $1$, we must choose to multiply by the power of $x$ term in the corresponding bracket, while for each digit in $b$ which is a $0$ we must multiply by the $1$ term. All in all there is only and exactly one way to form each non-negative integer $b$, and so expanding out the LHS produces the RHS term by term.